# Diff for humans not working in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

Hi am trying to use diffForHumans in laravel blade but its not working.please help
Heres my code

```
@foreach($students as @student)
   $time=$student->created_at->diffForHumans()
<td>@php echo $time;@endphp <td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: you must first parse your timestamp to carbon and then format it `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($student->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}` check the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) documentation

Answer (score 0):

`$student->created_at` is a string, hence you can't call `diffForHumans()` function on it. Instead, you should [parse it via Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing) instead. Here's how to do it

```
@foreach($students as @student)
    @php
        $time= \Carbon::parse($student->created_at)->diffForHumans()
    @endphp
    //Now do what you need to do
@endforeach
```

Also, you can't just write php code inside blade. If you do that, you need to contain the code inside @php tags as shown above. Although, it's not really clean to write php code in blade. With that being said, if you just want to display the time, here's how I would do it

```
@foreach($students as @student)
    <p>Created At : {{ \Carbon::parse($student->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

All You need is to parse the date using `Carbon` like this

{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($student->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}